# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

```
$ npm update minimatch@3.0.2

$ npm update -d
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.11.3
npm info using node@v0.12.7
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 5:33:55 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm info ok


$ npm install jshint
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
jshint@2.9.2 node_modules\jshint
├── strip-json-comments@1.0.4
├── exit@0.1.2
├── shelljs@0.3.0
├── console-browserify@1.1.0 (date-now@0.1.4)
├── lodash@3.7.0
├── minimatch@2.0.10 (brace-expansion@1.1.5)
├── htmlparser2@3.8.3 (domelementtype@1.3.0, entities@1.0.0, domhandler@2.3.0, d                                                                                                                omutils@1.5.1, readable-stream@1.1.14)
└── cli@0.6.6 (glob@3.2.11)
```

Comment: npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                                                                 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question? This site is for programming questions, not a place to dump some terminal output.

Comment: yes my question is did you face this problem before or have an idea how to solve it

Comment: @MohamedFared — What problem? It seems to be "I installed some third party software and the installer complained that it was using an old version of the library". It doesn't seem to have anything to do with any code you wrote. Your question reads like a bug report that should be directed at JS Hint.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I got the same error and still stuck. I found a guy solved this problem but I've not tested yet. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266691/error-npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-please-update-to-minimatch-3-0-2-or). OR You can follow this issue on https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13323 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply..

```
 sudo npm install
```

Try this..this works For me to install npm

To  update use this..

```
sudo npm install -g npm@3
```

Answer (score 5):

> npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2

try this....Should Work

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for OSX)

**Enter Into Terminal**    sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

Comment: While this is one way of going about this, I've always regarded it as the least favorable. Rather than change the owner of system files, it makes more sense to run `npm config set prefix $HOME/.node_modules` https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen.  You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me downgrading to node v4.4.7 and with sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I can fix it. 
   npm install minimatch 
+ minimatch@3.0.4
    sudo npm install -g minimatch@3.0.4
Try this. It run good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I worked in **reactJS** with **bebel** script and try to **install npm** in my directory. At that time I found this error. I have solved this error by below command.

Run this command in cmd:

> npm install browserify babelify babel-preset-env

Answer (score 0):

While `chown` is one way of going about this, I've always regarded it as the least favorable. Rather than change the owner of system files, it makes more sense to run `npm config set prefix $HOME/.node_modules`. This will configure npm to look for your `node_modules` in your home directory, rather than globally.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.