# Error: npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, installation

I have this problem during installation of ionic cordova:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

Please anyone helpme

Answer (score 10):

You need to update your minimatch version
Follow these steps:

Run this command to update minimatch

```
$ npm update minimatch
```

Run this command to check minimatch version

```
$ npm -v minimatch
```

If the version is still old one Run this command

```
$ npm install -g npm@3
```

Check your version again

```
$ npm -v minimatch
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I worked in **redux-Saga** and try to **install npm** in my directory. At that time I found this error. I have solved this error by below command,

Run this command in cmd:

```
   npm install browserify babelify babel-preset-env
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by deinstalling nodejs v4.x (64-bit) and installing the latest nodejs v6.3.0 (32-bit). after that i installed cordova with 'npm install -g cordova' 
I use a windows machine. I hope this helps anyone :-)

Before that i deleted all my node_modules npm and npm-cache folders in my home directory and appdata -> roaming directory

Comment: I done this, Its working At my machine. Hope it work for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

if your node js running in v 4.xx,

1. remove first your npm and npm cache on your appData/roaming ...
2. Uninstalling your node js
3. Upgrade your Node js to v6.x (or latest version)

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by re-installing node as suggested by [Erdendi Lesmana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377083/erdendi-lesmana). So now minimatch version is updated

```
$ npm -v minimatch
3.10.8
```

but I still cannot install cordova

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

can someone help please.

Comment: I was able to resolve only by downgrading npm and node version (I installed npm 2.4.2 and node 4.* any version which is not 3.10.8). As mentioned by Anna in the comment below. 

[https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14202#issuecomment-252073291][1]

Answer (score -1):

this is an npm error related to versioning. upgrade your minimatch to the latest version and the error will likely go away.